# Точность распознавания лиц с помощью Javacv

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Я новичок в javacv. Пробую создать систему распознавания лиц  и столкнулся с проблемой низкой точности распознавания. Для идентификации я использую EigenFaceRecognizer, а в качестве базы изображений для обучения использую Georgia Tech Face Database, а также свои собственные фото, все изображения в разрешении 640х480, лица расположены фронтально(10-12 фотографий для одного человека, всего 20 персон).

Результат распознавания получается очень нестабильным и работает через раз. Как можно повысить точность распознавания ? Стоит ли дополнительно редактировать фотографии перед обучением и распознаванием, или проблема заключается в неправильном обучении программы и стоит корректировать код ?

Заранее спасибо.

Функция обучения

```
public void train() {
        File imagesDir = new File("C:\\Java_Eclipse\\FaceRecognitionWebcam\\src\\image");
        FilenameFilter imgFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                name = name.toLowerCase();
                return name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".pgm") || name.endsWith(".png");
            }
        };

        File[] imageFiles = imagesDir.listFiles(imgFilter);
        MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);
        Mat labels = new Mat(imageFiles.length, 1, CV_32SC1);
        IntBuffer labelsBuf = labels.createBuffer();

        int counter = 0;

        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            Mat img = imread(image.getAbsolutePath(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            int label = Integer.parseInt(image.getName().split("\\-")[0]);
            images.put(counter, img);
            labelsBuf.put(counter, label);
            counter++;
        }

        // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = FisherFaceRecognizer.create();
         FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create();
        // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create();
        System.out.println("Train started");
        faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
        faceRecognizer.save("C:\\Java_Eclipse\\FaceRecognitionWebcam\\src\\train_result_eigen.xml");
        System.out.println("Train completed");

    }
```

Функция распознавания

```
public void findFaces(IplImage currentFrame) throws InterruptedException {
        IntPointer labels = new IntPointer(1);
        DoublePointer confidences = new DoublePointer(1);

        opencv_core.CvMemStorage storage = new opencv_core.CvMemStorage().create();
        opencv_core.CvSeq faces =
                cvHaarDetectObjects(currentFrame, classifierFace, storage, 1.6, 8, opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
        int total = faces.total();

        if(total > 0) {
            System.out.println("Total faces: " + total);
            for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                opencv_core.CvRect r = new opencv_core.CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
                int x = r.x(); int y = r.y(); int w = r.width(); int h = r.height();
                IplImage greyImg = IplImage.create(currentFrame.width(), currentFrame.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                cvCvtColor(currentFrame, greyImg, CV_RGB2GRAY);//resize
                rectangle(cvarrToMat(currentFrame), new Rect(x, y, w, h), new Scalar(0, 255, 0, 0), 2, 0, 0);
                faceRecognizer.predict(cvarrToMat(greyImg), labels, confidences);
                int label = labels.get(0);
                double confidence = confidences.get(0);
                String labelInfo = faceRecognizer.getLabelInfo(label).toString();
                System.out.println("---------");
                System.out.println("Person: " + i);
                System.out.println("label = " + label);
                System.out.println("confidence = " + confidence);


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала вам надо разобраться с этим

> > Результат распознавания получается очень нестабильным и работает через раз.

У вас должен быть набор картинок для обучения (train set) и тестовый набор картинок (test set) как минимум. После обучения на первом наборе нужно проверить и замерить точность на втором наборе, чтобы она выражалась одним числом, самое простое это процент распознанных картинок (accuracy).

Только после того, как есть метрика, можно что-то улучшать.

Напоследок, советы как улучшить точность распознавания с англоязычного сайта (см ответ)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191177/how-to-increase-the-accuracy-of-eigenfacerecognizer-it-recognizes-two-people-as

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, распознавание лиц на фотографиях работает хорошо, но вот с видео уже начинаются проблемы. Советы из данной Вами ссылки следует применять на набор картинок для обучения и видео, которое распознается, или только на видео, не затрагивая при этом набор для обучения ?

Comment: @SislaOpir, а у вас в наборе для обучения только фотографии, а тестируете вы и на фотографиях и видео?

Comment: Еще, у вас видео представляется как последовательность картинок и потом с каждой картинкой работаете отдельно?

Comment: Для обучения у меня используются только фотографии. При работе с видео каждую итерацию в цикле область с распознанным лицом конвертируется в фото, и потом это фото используется в качестве аргумента в методе predict.